# Find all merge in Ancestry Path

Tags: c#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

In Git, I can get all of need commits via

> git log  hash..master --ancestry-path --merges

Is there an equivalent to do this in LibGit2Sharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First some basics:**

> git log topic..master

```
var filter = new CommitFilter { 
    SortBy = CommitSortStrategies.Time,
    Since = master,
    Until = topic,
};
var commitList = repo.Commits.QueryBy (filter);
```

> git log topic..master --merges

```
var filter = new CommitFilter { 
    SortBy = CommitSortStrategies.Time,
    Since = master,
    Until = topic,
};
var commitList = repo.Commits.QueryBy (filter);
var mergeList = commitList.Where (p => p.Parents.Count () >= 2);
```

**Now to your question:**

git log topic..master --ancestry-path --merges

> ancestry-path =
>
> ```
>        When given a range of commits to display (e.g.  commit1..commit2 or
>        commit2 ^commit1), only display commits that exist directly on the
>        ancestry chain between the commit1 and commit2, i.e. commits that
>        are both descendants of commit1, and ancestors of commit2.
> ```

The `-merges` are easy once we have the ancestry path as we can filter the commits that have more then one parent. Getting the ancestry path requires some coding ;-)

Since the `ICommitLog` that is returned from `commitList` in the first example above contains a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) via the `.Parents` property, we need to walk the graph and get "all the simple paths” via a depth-first search to find all non-cyclical paths. Once you have a list of all the `simple` paths just filter it by which commits have `>=2` parents.

Note: I have done this in a few C# projects and even simple ones like calc'ing the pull-request related to a particular commit uses this depth-first ancestry. I tend to stay away from Linq to do this as I have `huge` commit lists (100k+ nodes between the start to end nodes within just the sub-DAG that I searching) and also avoid recursive methods due to stack size but your use-case may/will differ. If you get stuck at this point, post another question with your algorithm/code issue.